# getting consistent footer spacing

Tags: html, css

So guys, im simply trying to have a clean footer that will appear at the end of the page content consistently, whether or not the content fills up the length of the page.

As of now, I've tried a few options, first, i've done it with a sticky footer:

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
header {
    padding: 1em;
    background:#EFDECD; //#5ee;
    text-align: center;

}

.mydiv{
height:calc(100% - 4em);
}
p{
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
.paragraph{
font-size: 1em;
//font-family:  Charcoal, sans-serif;
}
#content {
    padding: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 7em;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
footer {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    height:4em;
//  position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #EFDECD; //#EFDECD
    text-align: center;
   overflow: hidden;
    a{
        padding: .75rem;
       // position:relative;
        top: 1.5em;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: .72rem;
    }
    p{
        font-size: .72rem;
    }
}

video{
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}
//header{
////margin-top: 3ems;
//    background-color: lightgrey;
//}

//footer{
//    height: 5em;
//    background-color: lightgrey;
//    position: relative;
//   bottom: 0px;
//   width: 100%;
//
//}
.label{
margin-left: .5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
}
table{
font-size: .75em;
}

.panel.callout a:not(.button):hover{
  color: $anchor-font-color-hover;
}

.headingtext{
font-family:  Century Gothic, sans-serif;

}
.headtext{
    display:inline-block;
 //   font-size:3em;
    margin: 0 10em;
    text-align: center;
 //   font-family:"Courier New";
  //  font-weight: bold;
 //   margin-left: 6em;

}
.img2{
   // max-height: 20%;
    max-width: 25%;
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
   }

.accorborder{
border: black dotted 1px;
}
h6{font-weight: bold;}


.top-bar-section .right li .dropdown { /* left: auto; */ right: auto; }
```

dl.tabs dd{background-color:$oil;} 
which works, but the footer is always visable and takes up screen space when there is important content on the page.

Ideally, I would like to change the position to 'absolute' and that looks fine on all the pages except on a page where there is not enough content, then the footer appears just below the content, and leaves a large white space gap from the footer to the bottomn of the page.

How can I simply make it so the footer always appears at the bottom of the page regardless of the page length? Also, feel free to inspect element to help. Currently its using the fixed position:

http://ops.emsofl.com/

Comment: I saved your page, found .midiv (apparently it was firedug intervention that I didn't see it before), deleted half of the content to see where the footer goes and it is right at the bottom of the page, there it supposed to be...  Try to reproduce it and we'll see what to do with it.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova thank you, for now i just .hide the footer because it is not that important but ill see if i can reproduce it sometime. I'm not sure how to reproduce it im using a lot of plug ins and things like scss, zurb foundation 5 it seems complex is there a way to do it?

Comment: You can either create a small working page and add all plug-ins to it in small chunks till it spots working or remove staff from the real page till it starts to work. The idea is to check the effect after each small change to detect what's causing the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it : set body and html to 100% height, then:

```
<div style="height:calc(100% - 30px);">
     <!-- 30px for footer -->
     <!-- header and content will be here -->
</div>
<footer style="height:30px;">must be fixed height</footer>
```

So, if you content is long, footer appears after it, if the page is empty, div will occupancy the whole screen anyway.

UPDATE try if it works in your browser [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qy5L0bck/)

P.S. I've got a small netbook and don't see much of your page as it is, just header, footer and two lines of content (OK, may be ten lines :) )

Comment: yea, i realzed that was an issue... maybe i should make the header smaller too?

Comment: what should i use for the positioning then? Because when i  'unfix' it, it looks good on the pages where the content goes to the bottom of the page but on the short content pages like the tab with just the 2 links, it looks bad.

Comment: thats not really a design feature, probably just the product of too many links in the nav bar. lol... on a wider screen it should all fit.

Comment: im trying to do your soluction, but where do i put the div? inside the body? Also, it will require a lot of changes because right now i have a a few divs already inside the body for content and wrapper. So im not sure where to add your div.

Comment: @codemonkey div wraps everything except the footer, so it's `<body><myDiv><everything else></myDiv><footer></body>` It shouldn't affect anything you've got there now.

Comment: thanks nadia but i have a problem on the main index.php page now. Every other page works well but the main page the footer is appearing in the middle of the page. I did what you said

Comment: its not the only one with not enough content, on some other pages with not enough content it works fine. It's just on the main page, I can put it on a different server I will post the link soon.

Comment: um you have to inspect element, I see the 'mydiv' class and the problem on the main page. The footer appears in the middle of the page but its behind that front pannel. On all other pages it appears correctly. Can you not see it still?

Comment: hmm i have this line: .mydiv{
height:calc(100% - 4em);
}

in my app.scss file. i am using chrome.

Comment: not sure why, i have it in css and i see it in index on the server .... let me post some code here maybe it will help because i have some other elements maybe they are interefere.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the footer into the content div and work with the `position: absolute` method you did.

It seems your body tag is not getting the full height of the page.. which probably is because you are floating elements and not clearing them properly, or you're using elements in the content div which are positioned absolute.. I haven't really checked the rest of the page..

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks do you know what elements are floating and how i can clear to get the body to span the full length of the page, thanks.